# Deployment of pubsub functions to European servers seems to be broken (error 13 "INTERNAL")

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have several pubsub functions deployed to europe-west1 but now that I try to add another one I get an error 13 "INTERNAL".

Deploying the same function to US or Asia works fine, just like it did for Europe a few days ago.

Is this a current outage?

Google Cloud Status Dashboard is all green though.

```
>firebase deploy --only functions:x

...

i  functions: uploading functions in project: x(europe-west1)
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function x(europe-west1)...
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
+  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-x-europe-west1 is up to date, no changes required
!  functions[x(europe-west1)]: Deployment error.
Failed to configure trigger PubSub projects/PROJECTNAME/topics/firebase-schedule-x-europe-west1


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        x
```

Log from GCP logs viewer:

```
{
 insertId: "-REDACTED"  
 logName: "projects/PROJECTNAME/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  
 operation: {
  id: "operations/REDACTED"   
  last: true   
  producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
 }
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "abc@xyz.de"    
  }
  methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"   
  requestMetadata: {
   destinationAttributes: {
   }
   requestAttributes: {
   }
  }
  resourceName: "projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/europe-west1/functions/x"   
  serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
   code: 13    
   message: "INTERNAL"    
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-21T12:51:31.393522595Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "x"    
   project_id: "PROJECTNAME"    
   region: "europe-west1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2020-05-21T12:51:30.732Z"  
}
```

I tested all servers available for functions:

```
asia-east2          OK
asia-northeast1     OK
europe-west1        FAIL
europe-west2        FAIL
europe-west3        FAIL
us-central1         OK
us-east1            OK
us-east4            OK
```

Tested with firebase-tools 8.3.0 and 8.2.0

**Edit 2020-05-22**

I found a workaround:

The problem seems to be the creation of pub/sub topics.
If I go to

https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic/list

and create a topic that fits my new function's expect pattern

```
firebase-schedule-FUNCTIONNAME-REGIONNAME
```

then I can deploy new functions.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: @Tom does my workaround work for you?

Comment: @Mark, I can confirm your workaround working good, thanks.

Comment: @Mark It started working without doing anything!

Comment: @Tom looks like they fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google seems to have fixed it.
If it ever occurs, try the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the Firebase support team.

> This was a known issue; we were experiencing some deployments problems
>   in some regions, the engineering has been working to mitigate this
>   issue, and I verified the deployment process with a function sample in
>   the region asia-northeast1, and the deployment was successful. So, I
>   encourage you to try again, and if the issue persists, the next
>   workaround can help to solve the problem. Manually create the topic
>   first in the Google Cloud Console or using the gcloud CLI (gcloud
>   pubsub topics create), and then deploy the function using that
>   function.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms sounds like a backend problem, since the error 13 can come due to several reasons, but when it happens that the same function works on another regions it is possible that you are facing a stock out issue.

I would suggest to wait another day or week to try the creation again, anyway you can perform requests to the closest available location. Review the available regions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones)

Comment: What is a stock out issue?
The error still occurs, but it seems to be related to pub/sub topics and permissions (please see my edit).
As for the region I need EU out of legal reasons so I'm stuck there.

Comment: The stock out issue refers to the lack of physical resources to the specific regions, recently there where problems as pointed in the other answers.